# SQL query using attribute (harddisk_name) from another table (harddisk)

Tags: mysql

I have the tables imagecapturing, harddisks.

imagecapturing:

```
id, manuscript_shelfmark, harddisk_id
61, foo, 4
70, bar, 5
90, baz, 6
```

harddisks:

```
id, harddisk_name
4, hd-1
5, hd-2
6, hd-3
```

I'm looking for a SQL query that prints all records by querying with only harddisk_name (instead of harddisk_id)?

```
manuscript_shelfmark, harddisk_name
foo,               hd-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT manuscript_shelfmark, harddisk_name
FROM imagecapturing
LEFT JOIN harddisks ON imagecapturing.harddisk_id = harddisks.id 
WHERE harddisks.name = 'hd-1';
```

Comment: could change `LEFT JOINT` to `JOIN` as the `WHERE` criteria is after a non-`NULL` entry.